# How to get list of wikipedia articles that are in specified category?

Tags: wikipedia-api

If I use this URL to get the Category page

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&callback=jQuery111206430303168017417_1453394474227&action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Category%3AHacker+(subculture)&_=1453394474245
```

but I only have a header and other categories, how to get the same page as on Wikipedia with a list of articles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Wikimedia API does not return the HTML page as it appears when you browse Wikipedia. If you want that page, you need to call it by its common URL, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Hacker_%28subculture%29

If you want to use the API to get at the page titles or page ids listed in a certain category, you need to query for **category members**.

For your query, you would do something like: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AHacker+%28subculture%29

Set `cmlimit` to get more than the default ten pages. Maximum is 500.

You can then parse the JSON to get at the listed page titles or page ids, e.g. to create links to those pages.

Look at [the documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers) for an explanation of these and other parameters you may use in your query.

The query uses `format=jsonfm` (for a readable rendering of the data) as a default. Use `format=json` for your data query.